# Cannot create custom mount point for /dev in systemd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, upstart, systemd

I am working in an embedded system and we are migrating from upstart to systemd. I am trying to write .mount file for /dev in rootfs. But this failing. Can somebody please help ?

```
#  This file is part of systemd.
#
#  systemd is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it
#  under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2.1 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.

[Unit]
Description=/dev Directory
Documentation=man:hier(7)
Documentation=http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems
DefaultDependencies=no
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=local-fs.target umount.target

[Mount]
What=tmpfs
Where=/dev
Type=tmpfs
Options=mode=1777
```

My filename is `dev.mount`.

I am getting the following error
`Cannot add dependency job for unit dev.mount, ignoring: Unit dev.mount failed to load: Invalid argument`

Answer (score 1):

excerpt from documentation of
[systemd.mount](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html)

> Some file systems have special semantics as API file systems for kernel-to-userspace and userspace-to-userspace interfaces. Some of them may not be changed via mount units, and cannot be disabled.

See also:
[API file systems](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/APIFileSystems/)